# Preserving $rootScope while browsing between states

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I developed a single page application with `index.html` file and 2 views `view1.html` and `view2.html` and configured 2 states for the above views but when I'm browsing between the states I'm losing the data I just stored in `$rootScope` because the browser loading the `app.js` again.

Should it be like that? how can I store data inside the `$rootscope` and preserve it while browsing from `state 1` to `state 2`?

Comment: Store in a controller but when you refresh the page all data will be gone. You have to request for the data on refresh

Comment: Why do you refresh the page when change from one view to other?? ..it's not correct for a SPA ..

Comment: How do you navigates between views? Using hash bangs or url change with full page refresh?

Comment: @federicoscamuzzi for some reason the link refresh the page when browsing from view 1 to view 2. i am using ui-router and i see on fiddler that it refresh the entire index file. What could be the problem?

Comment: post your code plz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found that i had to write the links as:

`<a ui-sref="testa()">View2</a>`

instead of

`<a href="site/testa">View2</a>`

Answer (score 0):

If app.js is the code which contains your main app, it should ideally be loaded only once when you first time load the page, and after that all your page transitions should be replacing some data container through ajax.....thus ensuring the $rootScope remains preserved.

If this is not your structure and you are refreshing the page regularly you are not following the basic tenet of SPA

Comment: i thought that ui-router should use AJAX when i am changing scopes\view and using the ui-view. isn't that true?

Comment: yes it does and in that case your rootScope should be preserved if you are navigating using the ui router

Comment: for some reason its not the case. could you give it a try and see? i almost sure you will found that the whole page is getting refreshed while using href from page to page.

Comment: I have done this in my current project....the whole page does not get refreshed......can you post your controller code.....the controller which gets called when you navigate to a particular link.....

Comment: i found that i didn't use ui-sref. i thought i can still use the regular href. Thanks for your time.